# Determining if a recursion call has no solution

Tags: python, recursion

We have the following recursive algorithm, giving all possible combinations of the given amounts to reach a certain goal. Using it in another context, I was wondering if there is a way to explicitly announce that there is no solution, instead of giving no output.

```
def purchase_possibilities(self, amounts, goal, current=[], highest=0, curr_sum=0, index=0):
    # See if we are done.
    if curr_sum == goal:
        self.display(current, amounts, index)
        return

    if curr_sum > goal:
        return

    for value in amounts:
        if value >= highest:
            # Copy the current list, then add the current value.
            copy = current[:]
            copy.append(value)
            # Recursively add more current.
            self.purchase_possibilities(amounts, goal, copy, value, curr_sum + value, index=index)

def display(self, current, amounts, index):
    # Display our combinations sorted by amount.
    for amount in amounts:
        count = current.count(amount)
        print("* -> " + self.get_product_name(amount, index), ":", count)
    print()
```

For example, if I give for example amounts = [20, 3, 5, 7.95] and goal = 28.79
I want the program to tell me that there is no possible combination to arrive to that answer, instead of just giving no output.

Comment: Why not **return** results then rather than print? Then you can return `None` if there is no solution.

Comment: You want to find all the subsets of `amounts` that add up to goal?

Comment: Yes the code works. It's a subset_sum function indeed. However, finding all the amounts is not a problem. What I want is to determine if there is a way to reach the solution or not. 
I am trying to edit it at the moment to see if I can put returns instead of prints, but returns in recursive functions function a bit differently, since the last call of the function isn't the one you get as a return value, but rather the first.

Comment: what do you want to display, just a message at the end if no valid combination was found?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I'd rather set a flag to False for example. Returning   a value seems impossible in this case, so I guess that would be the best thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a flag and always return it, setting it to True only if of get a `curr_sum == goal`.

```
flag = [False]
def purchase_possibilities(amounts, goal, current=[], highest=0, curr_sum=0, index=0):
    # See if we are done.
    if curr_sum == goal:
        flag[0] = True
        return self.display(current, amounts)

    if curr_sum > goal:
        return []

    for value in amounts:
        if value >= highest:
            copy = current[:]
            copy.append(value)  
            # Copy the current list, then add the current value.
            # Recursively add more current.
            self.purchase_possibilities(amounts, goal, copy, value, curr_sum + value, index=index)
    return flag[0]
```

If you want a message you can do something like:

```
  return "No valid combination" if not flag[0]  else ""
```

Also on a side note when using mutable default args you might be better setting the initial value to `None` and doing the same with the flag as successive calls will potentially give incorrect output:

```
def purchase_possibilities(amounts, goal, current=None, highest=0, curr_sum=0, index=0, flag=None):
    # See if we are done.
    if flag is None:
        flag = [False]
    if  current is None:
        current = []
```

And changing the line to  `self.purchase_possibilities(amounts, goal, copy, value, curr_sum + value, index=index,flag=flag)`

Answer (score -1):

It should be quite simple to rewrite your recursive method to this; you have both inputs available: the list of amounts and the goal. No solution would be indicated by an empty list which can be tested in Pythonic way "if not "

```
from itertools import *

# given a list, produce a generator which yields all possible
# subsets of the list
def allsubsets(l):
    for s in chain( *map(lambda r: combinations(l,r), xrange(len(l))) ):
        yield s
# filter the subsets whose sum is equal to the amount
goal_finder = lambda goal, amounts: \
                filter(lambda subset: sum(subset)==goal, allsubsets(amounts))

print goal_finder(29.75, [10,20,9,0.75])
```

Output:

```
[(20, 9, 0.75)]
```

Comment: However I need all possibilities, and yes, I can use itertools but I'm trying to do this using a recursive method. I do agree that this is a simpler solution though.

Comment: I think this _does_ give all possibilities. And you could hide it in the member function and take appropriate action upon inspecting the result of the `goal_finder()` - either set a flag or do other intricate things.